# Android SipManager make application to crash

Tags: java, android, voip, sip

I am developing a simple sip-based voip app for android.
I used this [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html) but there were some problems and I decided to write it step-by-step.

First I want to do registration on server. I do:

```
SipManager manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);  
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(number, server);
builder.setPassword(password);
SipProfile me = builder.build();
```

And it works fine. But when I do

```
manager.register(me, 1000, null);
```

or

```
manager.open(me)
```

my app crashed. I test this on Samsung i9000.
I think a problem is somewhere in wifi connection. 
Any advices how to fix?

Comment: could you provide the printed stack trace?

Comment: No, I could not even do USB-debugging, my eclipse can't "see" my phone. I just setup an app to it and try to run...

Comment: You should try running it in debug mode connected to eclipse, that should give you a lot more to go on of what the problem might be

Comment: Ok, i'll try to do this and than post a stack trace here.

Comment: I cant post it here, it is too big. Here are some: 09-21 15:31:39.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-21 15:31:39.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9087): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    09-21 15:31:39.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9087):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check with SipManager.isApiSupported() and SipManager.isVoipSupported() is SIP is supported on your device. Perhaps Samsung disabled the SIP API.

Comment: It was really blocked by Samsung.